# Program to calculate grade

Tags: python

I am writing a python program to calculate the test grade of 5 students and it will show what grade they get by entering their test score. But I can't get a result like this. Can someone help me out, please!
5
88
92
76
100
66
Grade Distribution
A: 2
B: 1
C: 1
D: 1
F: 0
Average Grade: 84.4

```
`def read_test_scores():
    print("Enter number of students: ")
    num = int(input())


    print("Enter the next grade: ")
    score1 = int(input())
    score2 = int(input())
    score3 = int(input())
    score4 = int(input())
    score5 = int(input())        
    sum = (score)
    tavge = sum / 5.0
    return tavge

def get_letter_grade():
    if 90 <= n <= 100:
        grade = 'A'
    elif 80 <= n <= 89:
        grade = 'B'
    elif 70 <= n <= 79:
        grade = 'C'
    elif 60 <= n <= 69:
        grade = 'D'
    elif n<60:
        grade = 'F'
    return grade

def print_comment(grade):
    a=0
    b=0
    c=0
    d=0
    f=0
    
    if grade == 'A':
        a += 1
        print ('A: ' +str(a))
    elif grade == 'B':
        b += 1
        print ('B: ' +str(b))
    elif grade == 'C':
        c += 1
        print ('C: ' +str(c))
    elif grade == 'D':
        d +=1
        print ('D: ' +str(d))
    elif grade == 'F':
        f +=1
        print ('F: ' +str(f)) 

tavge = read_test_scores()
print ('Grade Distribution')
print_comment(grade) 
print ("Test Average is:    " + str(tavge))`
```

Comment: get_letter_grade is not used

Comment: On top of what @Xiao_e_yun said, you also have another issue. `sum = (score)` isn't valid either. Change it to `my_sum = sum(score)` and then change the next line to `tvage = my_sum / 5.0`

Comment: I think it needs to be refactored lol

Comment: why you make it very difficult even you can define in easy method.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I think you were going for.  I had to make several changes that I can clarify if needed... Mostly you needed to store the scores and grades as an array of values instead of individual ones.  When you need to, for instance, tally up the number of A's, B's, etc. you just loop through the array and add up the occurrences.

```
def read_test_scores():
    print("Enter number of students: ")
    num = int(input())

    scores = []
    print("Enter the next grade: ")
     for score in range(num):

        score = int(input())
        while score < 0 or score > 100:
            print('Score should be between 0 and 100, try again:')
            score = int(input())
        
        scores.append(score)

    sum_scores = sum(scores)
    tavge = sum_scores / num
    return tavge, scores

def get_letter_grade(n):
    if 90 <= n <= 100:
        grade = 'A'
    elif 80 <= n <= 89:
        grade = 'B'
    elif 70 <= n <= 79:
        grade = 'C'
    elif 60 <= n <= 69:
        grade = 'D'
    elif n<60:
        grade = 'F'
    return grade

def print_comment(grades): 

    a=0
    b=0
    c=0
    d=0
    f=0   
    
    for grade in grades:
        if grade == 'A':
            a += 1
        elif grade == 'B':
            b += 1
        elif grade == 'C':
            c += 1
        elif grade == 'D':
            d +=1
        elif grade == 'F':
            f +=1
    print ('A: ' +str(a))
    print ('B: ' +str(b))
    print ('C: ' +str(c))
    print ('D: ' +str(d))
    print ('F: ' +str(f)) 

tavge, scores = read_test_scores()

grades = []
for score in scores:
    grades.append(get_letter_grade(score))

print ('Grade Distribution')
print_comment(grades)


print ("Test Average is:    " + str(tavge))
```

Comment: Just add `assert grade>100` to function `get_letter_grade()`. In current code, if the grade is more than 100, `UnboundLocalError` is raised. If you get unexpected input, function _shouldn't_ end with not customised error message, because it looks kinda messy

Comment: I don’t think you need to worry about this problem

Comment: Great point. I edited to include checks when the scores are being read in, in case they're needed at some other point, in which case you'd have to use multiple asserts.

Comment: I also realized I need to store the score, but I just can't figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Barry The scores are contained in the scores list.  Do you need to store it as a file?  If so, the steps would be to open a file, and then loop over the list and write each score to the file

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea

Get number of students
Create total_score, or any Something you need to record
for in Students
Get score then add in total_score

```
total_score = 0
for i in range(student_number) :
    score = int(input())
    total_score += score
    # get_letter_grade

average = total_score / student_number
print ("Test Average is" + str())
```

Comment: get_letter_grade is about the same

Comment: Thanks! This gives me an idea to type less code but get the same output!